# Is it possible to add data to wordpress via email? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email

I would like to figure out a way to add some data to the administration of wordpress by sending an email. Is that even a possibility?

I would send a email to some email address and use keywords to add the data to the administration.

Thanks for help.